# Expo: No native splash screen registered for provided activity. Please configure your application's main Activity to call 'SplashScreen.show'

Tags: javascript, android, typescript, react-native, expo

Unhandled promise rejection: Error: No native splash screen registered for given view controller. Call 'SplashScreen.show' for given view controller first. (https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/main/packages/expo-splash-screen#-configure-android).

I get the following warning only on my android emulator when launching the app.

My Expo SDK is 47 and my React Native version is 0.70.5.

App.tsx

```
import React, { useCallback } from 'react';
import {ThemeProvider} from 'styled-components'

import { View } from 'react-native';

import { Routes } from './src/routes';
import { AppProvider } from './src/hooks';

import * as SplashScreen from 'expo-splash-screen';
import * as Font from 'expo-font';

import { 
  Roboto_300Light,
  Roboto_400Regular,
  Roboto_500Medium,
  Roboto_700Bold,
 } from '@expo-google-fonts/roboto';

SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();

export default function App() {
  
  const [fontsLoaded] = Font.useFonts({
    Roboto_300Light, Roboto_400Regular, Roboto_500Medium, Roboto_700Bold
  })

  const onLayout = useCallback(async () => {
    if(fontsLoaded){
      await SplashScreen.hideAsync();
    }
  }, [fontsLoaded])


  if(!fontsLoaded){
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <View style={{flex:1}} onLayout={onLayout}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <AppProvider>
          <Routes />
        </AppProvider>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </View>
  )
}
```

This warning is currently showing in the Android build.
iOS is working fine.

Answer (score -1):

Did you follow the Expo modules installation?

https://docs.expo.dev/bare/installing-expo-modules/

This was my issue.